# PDO storing FetchAll result in variable vs using directly in foreach

Tags: php, pdo, fetchall

So curiosity got to me. I always try to avoid creating variables that will only be used once, instead I try to use it directly (unless it's a lot of text, for example MySQL queries).

What I usually do is something like this:

```
$getSomethingSql = 'LONG SQL';
$getSomething = $dbConnection->prepare($getSomethingSql); // or query if no parameters are needed
// Some binds etc if needed
$getSomething->execute(); // if prepared statements are used
$something = $getSomething->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($something as $s) {}
```

Now, the `$getSomethingSql` is only used once but is stored as a variable since it can be a long string and thus this looks better. However, I was curious if there is any advantage of using above versus the code below:

```
$getSomethingSql = 'LONG SQL';
$getSomething = $dbConnection->prepare($getSomethingSql); // or query if no parameters are needed
// Some binds etc if needed
$getSomething->execute(); // if prepared statements are used

foreach ($getSomething->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $s) {}
```

Does these 2 codes do the same? And is there a (huge) performance difference, or is one of them cleaner?

Comment: Better may be to use your own class or wrapper function - pass it a SQL query and some parameters, have it run the PDO prepared statement, and use the `fetchAll()` to return back the record set as an array, which can then be used in your code.  This way, you aren't re-writing your DB connections, error checking, etc. and when updates happen you have one place to update

Comment: Well, the code I'm working in isn't mine and it actually always includes a "config" file containing the database connection. Even then, it could be done both ways I describe above, meaning I'd still wonder the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally they'll do the same thing. The only difference is that in one case it will use your explicitly created variable to hold the results of `fetchAll()` and in the second case it will make use of a temporary variable.